# Google Chrome and ValidateAntiForgeryToken prevents login screen from submitting 2nd time

Tags: google-chrome, asp.net-core

I have the following cshtml Login page

```
@{
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_MyLayout.cshtml";
 }
<form asp-area="Admin" asp-controller="Account" asp-action="Login" asp-route-returnurl="@ViewData["ReturnUrl"]" method="post" class="form-signin" role="form">
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    <input asp-for="Username" class="form-control" required="" autofocus="" />
    <span asp-validation-for="Username" class="text-danger"></span>
    <input asp-for="Password" class="form-control input-md" required="" />
    <span asp-validation-for="Password" class="text-danger"></span>

    <button  type="submit">Login</button>
    <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
</form>
```

and the following controller Methods

```
   [HttpGet]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    public IActionResult Login()
    {
        return View();
    }



    [HttpPost]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Login(LoginViewModel model)
    {

        if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                 ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, "You may not log in");
                 return View(model);
```

This  works in Internet Explorer. However in Chrome there is a problem.

In Chrome I click Login then it hits my post method and returns the invalid login message to my browser. However when I click  the returned page login again for a 2nd time it gives me for a millisecond an error message in my javascript browser console and then dissapears and then shows a blank page.

If I comment out the `[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]` the 2nd login attempt hits the Login Post method in Chrome correctly.

So the issue is limited to the ValidateAntiForgeryToken attribute existing on the POST and the browser being Chrome. Internet Explorer doesn't have the problem and hits the POST every time.